# Run Teampass in docker with a running nginx proxy

Tags: mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

@Moderators: can you please add the Tag teampass to the tag list?

I want to run [Teampass](http://teampass.net/) as a docker container with a nginx as a proxy.

I'm not sure if the problem, that Teampass brings it own Apache and works against my nginx or, if I got something else completely wrong.

I enter this like this
[image]

The problem is, that it's not passing this page, because the connection to the mySQL port is not working.

When I try to install it, without a running nginx , everything works as expected. But when I'm using nginx, it's not running anymore

docker-compose file:

```
teampass:
container_name: teampass
image: teampass/teampass
ports:
- 127.0.0.1:8787:80
volumes:
- /opt/teampass:/teampass
links:
- teampass_mysql

teampass_mysql:
restart: always
image: mysql/mysql-server:5.5
ports:
- 127.0.0.1:13306:3306
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=TEAMPASS_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_DATABASE=TEAMPASS_MYSQL_DATABASE
- MYSQL_PASSWORD=TEAMPASS_MYSQL_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_USER=TEAMPASS_MYSQL_USER
volumes:
- /opt/dbteampass:/var/lib/mysql
```

nginx file:

```
upstream teampass {
    server 127.0.0.1:8787;
}

upstream sqlteampass {
    server 127.0.0.1:13306;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_tokens off;
  server_name teampass.domain.tld;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_tokens off;
  server_name teampass.domain.tld;

  ssl_certificate /path/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://teampass;
  }
}



server {
  listen 80;
  server_tokens off;
  server_name sql.teampass.domain.tld;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_tokens off;
  server_name sql.teampass.domain.tld;

  ssl_certificate /path/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://sqlteampass;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you bind to `localhost` in the compose file? Have you tried just specifying the ports?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jcherqui/docker-teampass
Once you've got that working, you could add a reverse proxy to the mix. 
Check out traefik, which is a reverse proxy optimized for containers: https://traefik.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you get networking between your containers properly working.

Let's start with a barebones compose file, note that I'm leaving out the volume directive for now:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
  teampass:
      image: teampass/teampass
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      links:
          - db
  db:
      image: mysql:latest
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=teampass
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
          - MYSQL_USER=user
```

If you still have your old teampass container running, make sure you get rid of the old containers via `docker-compose rm -v` !

Now run, `docker-compose up`, once you see the db and teampass container are running, you can validate that the docker containers can see each other:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
263d801cdf85        teampass/teampass   "/bin/sh -c /start.sh"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       dockerteampass_teampass_1
fcb750fffd4f        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   dockerteampass_db_1
```

Note down the name of YOUR running teampass container.

```
$ docker exec -it dockerteampass_teampass_1 bash
```

Now you're inside the teampass container. To ping the db container, simply do

```
$ ping db
```

This should NOT timeout!

Now go to your browser and start the setup, make sure you enter `db` as the host!

This should remove your above error. **Once you have this working**, you can try to reverse proxy via nginx.

[image]

To learn more about docker networking see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

Comment: ahhhhhhhh the problem was the hostname...  it must be the docker container name....   yeah. thanks a lot!!